# Your usual setup for blogpost matrix field

Tags: matrix

What is your usual setup for blogpost/article matrix field?

I can think of:

- Header
- Richfield
- Quote (author+text)
- Image(asset, position, description)

Comment: I'm not sure if this may be considered as offtopic/too broad/opinion based since there is no real answer to this question.  You may want to ask this in Slack (https://craftcms.com/community) or some other place or specify the question to a certain problem (eg how to provide the different templates, fetch the blocks...). Besides that my answer would be: My setup is what the client needs/requests. There is no "usual" setup since all projects are highly customized

Answer (score 1):

Something like this: [Creating a Content Builder in Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/creating-a-content-builder-in-craft-cms)